# New QASM2ParseError for old circuit on IBM composer

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, teleportation, qasm

A while ago I wrote an example of quantum teleportation circuit in the IBM Composer which ran fine as of three days ago.  Yesterday, however, when I try to run the circuit, I get the following error:

> Failed - QASM2ParseError: '<input>:27,1: needed a start-of-statement token, but instead got /

I am using the IBM Composer and not writing the OpenQASM 2.0 code directly, but of course the composer writes the code automatically.  The line that seems to be causing a problem is at the end, and seems to be there due to using 'Freeform alignment' in the composer:

`// @columns [0,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]`

If I delete that line the code will run, but I lose the freeform alignment and hence visual organization in the composer.   Is there a way to keep the freeform alignment line and still get working code?

Comment: Could you add the circuit link to your question? Under "File" menu, click on "Share" to get this link.

Comment: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcIAqMA2MAOB7ATgFwjwEsswQAaEARwgGcoEQB5ABQFEA5ARQEEBlALIACAEwA6AAwBuADpgiYAMaoArgBMYQmdTREARgEYxCxdtlg5VHDADmQqgG0AzAF1zi63cXO3cuSoAKDCIhAHohABZyIWCwyOjY8JEASnsHCV8wPQgcHCIYHDSM82zc-MLHA0zSvIK0kUyACzSq9wAPFpdoxwaSnNqK9Or%2B8s6%2BsrqezMUOxwzuh1a5ZrnhicHiuRrRyrWB%2BszYOhVrTqEAWgA%2BIW8lsCPaE81Vi%2BvvTfkAMyEAxSEAXn%2BolSswcvTkRG%2BvwBQKcIIO5khPz%2BgKEBlSAC8ERCoSjYZjsRYwKFwgABRRYVRQMC0ITpcgGBlMpzkKIAVnIHI5ADZyAB2cgADiFIoAnAyJAzGQYRAyWQYIi4KCANLQPEQMMRSIwQABfIA

Answer (score 0):

According to [Open Quantum Assembly Language](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1707.03429) by Cross et. la.

> Comments begin with a pair of forward slashes and end with a new line.

Now, the line

```
// @columns [0,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

is the last line in the OpenQasm panel. That is, it doesn't end with a new line. Which means that this error happens due to a bug in IBM Quantum Composer.
As a workaround, just add an empty line after it, and your circuit should run without any issue.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the problem!